# Javascript How to get today and tomorrow date format like "22.11.2022 Tuesday"

Tags: javascript, react-native, date

I couldn't find the solution.
How to get date in `"Tuesday 22.11.2022"` format.

this is how i did it

```
 const date = new Date();
  const day = date.getDate();
  const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const today = day + '.' + month + '.' + year;
  const tomorrow = day + 1 + '.' + month + '.' + year;
```

Is there any way to get today's and tomorrow's date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the built-in [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat). You can either replace `/` with `.` in the date or use a locale that prefers dots ([Turkish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Turkey) for example).

```js
const today = new Date();
const tomorrow = new Date(today);
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);

const locale = "tr"; // set to `undefined` to use the browser default

// Using "en" for the day name since you seem to want it in English
const dayFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en", { weekday: "long" });
const dateFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {
  year: "numeric",
  month: "2-digit",
  day: "2-digit",
});

const formatDate = (date) =>
  `${dayFormatter.format(date)} ${dateFormatter.format(date)}`;

console.log("today:", formatDate(today));
console.log("tomorrow:", formatDate(tomorrow));
```

<sub>Note: JavaScript's `Date` does not deal with [September 1752](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/julian-gregorian-switch.html)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

With Vanilla JS

```js
const options = {
    weekday: 'long',
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'numeric',
    year: 'numeric',
};

const date = new Date();
var date2 = new Date();
date2.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);


const today = date.toLocaleDateString(
    'en-gb', options
).split('/').join('.').replace(/,/g, '');

const tommorow = date2.toLocaleDateString(
    'en-gb', options
).split('/').join('.').replace(/,/g, '');


console.log(today);
console.log(tommorow);
```

With [MomentJs](https://momentjs.com/)

```js
var today = moment().format('dddd DD.MM.YYYY');
var tomorrow =  moment().add(1, 'days').format('dddd DD.MM.YYYY');

console.log(today);
console.log(tomorrow);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Even Moment.js says [not to use Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Phil. Though, it is still working. I updated my answer to resolve the issue you raise.

Answer (score -4):

```
dateFns.format(new Date, "DD.MM.YYYY dddd")
```

I think it's very hard to do with vanilla js, because assume today is march 31, you get the day equal to 31, you get tomorrow by plus 1 to it => and you got 32

Comment: This would presumably require some kind of 3rd-party library which OP hasn't mentioned in the question or its tags